# How to add join query into yii search function

Tags: php, yii

> What I wanna know is, how to add join query into yii search function.
>
> Search function is in the currency model.(currency.php)

```
>public function search()
    {

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id,true);
        $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
        $criteria->compare('sign',$this->sign,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
```

> I wanna add the join query to that function.
>   Myquery is like that:
>
> SELECT * 
>   FROM currency cur
>   INNER JOIN currency_option curopt ON cur.id = curopt.currency_id
>   AND curopt.company_id =  '$com_id'.
>
> Anyone please help me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->join="INNER JOIN currency_option curopt ON cur.id = curopt.currency_id AND curopt.company_id = '$com_id'";
$criteria->compare('id',$this->id,true);
$criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
$criteria->compare('sign',$this->sign,true);
```

Try this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But cur.id is not ok. So I change t.id = curopt.currency_id.

Comment: @Thyu , sorry for my mistake. I had just copy paste from your query above.